# How to send audio from Yamaha MG16XU to Scarlett 2i2?

Tags: audio, mixer

I am currently working for a radio station. And we're planning to live stream a program on youtube. Webcam mic is too noisy so I want to use the radio stream sound as youtube stream audio. But I don't know how to connect.

I partially read the docs of both machines and found this question asked:

[Connecting audio interface to mixer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/31728/connecting-audio-interface-to-mixer)

But I am pretty new to this stuff and there is a lot of things I don't understand. Uploaded the pics below, can you show me how to connect these two?
Note: Can't pull any cables from the mixer.

[mixer](http://prntscr.com/lwgmtl)

[scarlett_back](http://prntscr.com/lwgnek)

[scarlett_front](http://prntscr.com/lwgno7)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough information. Is your radio station *generating* the youtube audio, for streaming to youtube, or are you going to pick the program up from youtube and retransmit it to the outside world? Does the 'radio station' have a sound engineer?

Comment: We dont have an engineer. We're producing a program which have two journalists and a guest candidate for upcoming elections. Q&A kinda thing. We can get clean audio from mics there and route it to radio main stream. We also want that program on youtube but don't know how to route that clean audio to the computer.

Comment: Have you looked at OBS (Open Broadcaster Software)? Usually used for video, but it should work for audio also; connect the mixer to the computer, the computer to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, no answer.

Should be pretty straightforward, I guess. Best solution would be to simply connect usb of the yamaha to the computer.

To send from the mixer to the 2i2 the straightforward option would be to connect Group out 1 to 2i2#1 and Group out 2 to 2i2#2 you can use TRS cables since the yamaha seems to have balanced output and the 2i2 has balanced inputs, I guess. The switches on front of the 2i2 should be set to line instead of instrument of course. **Do not use TRS to XLR cable** since XLR on the 2i2 is only for mic and messing with the phantom power could very well shredder one of your devices.

Then simply route the channels you want to send to the 2i2 to group 1+2 by pressing the appropriate button on those channels and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

See page 24 of the manual – PDF below ... the outputs are usually on the back ... plug and play, XLR to XLR - block 4 in the diagram. You won't need to press 24 volts on the Scarlett ... that's for powering an unpowered mic ... the Yahmaha is powered.

"[image]

https://www.soundpro.com/content/product-documents/Yamaha_MG12_16_20_OM.pdf